# Why can't I instantiate the Win32_PowerMeter WMI class?

Tags: c#, wmi, power-management

I've seen many examples of instantiating subclasses of the WMI `Win32 Classes`.  For example, trying the query the Win32_Battery class:

```
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
...
ManagementClass mgmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
ManagementObjectCollection o = mgmt.getInstances();
```

However, this query fails, it tells me it is an unknown class and cannot be instantiated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Win32_PowerMeter is not in the default namespace.  Sample code generated by the [WMI Code Creator utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) that shows the correct namespace:

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2\\power", 
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerMeter"); 

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Win32_PowerMeter instance");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}", queryObj["DeviceID"]);
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for you help, that was great. Now the problem is that most of the properties for some strange reasopn are null. I can get Id and Name...but that's pretty much it. Any clue?

Comment: Also I assume I can instantiate CIM_NumericSensor in the same way right?

Comment: No.  Quote from the docs: `WMI does not implement this class. For classes derived from CIM_NumericSensor, see Win32 Classes.`  Use the linked WMI Code Creator utility to experiment.